Validation Taking too long
I am currently training a UNet-like architecture to reconstruct audio. The training is going smoothly. The issue is that I am performing certain evaluations (like rt60 and drr) that need to be computed on the cpu which is causing an immense overhead of time. Validation of just 1000 batches of 32 audios is taking around 15 hours - understandably so. I move the entire batch to memory and compute whatever is needed, log and it and move to the next batch.
How can I speed this up?
I tried multiprocessing but that didnt make a difference.

To clarify: are you running both the UNet and your evaluation metrics on cpu? I guess you should run the UNet in GPU and afterwards move the output to cpu before computing the mentioned cpu metrics.
